# How to dynamically add React componsents from websockets

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, websocket

I've been working through a couple of tutorials on integrating Django and React, and making some modifications to learn the platform better. So far, when the page loads, React queries Django REST api and, based on that input, loads a number of City components. The code looks like this:

```
class CityList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cities: [],
      newCities: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/").then(res => {
      this.setState({
        cities: res.data
      });
      document.body.style.background = "#131C2F";
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.articles);
    return (
      <div className="row" id="mainRow" style={{ backgroud: "#304877" }}>
        <div className="col-lg-9 col-sm-10" style={{ backgroud: "#304877" }}>
          <ul className="mainList">
            {this.state.cities.map(city => {
              return <Cities city={city} />;
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-2" style={{ backgroud: "#304877" }}>
          <div className="form-signin search-box" style={{ position: "fixed" }}>
            <h1
              className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal"
              style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: "22px", color: "white" }}
            >
              Add location
            </h1>
            <br />

            <input
              type="text"
              name="location"
              id="myLocation"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="City"
            />
            <br />
            <div
              className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              Add
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried adding a web socket which would push new City components from Django backend. The socket is created by:

```
var mySocket = new WebSocket('url to backend');
```

This also works fine, and receives objects in the format needed to populate City components. However, I can't figure out how to write a function which uses the data from websocket, makes a component, and loads it to the page.

I presume one of the ways would be to update the state of the CityList component, which is why I added 'newCities' to the state, but can't seem to go further than that.

Any pointers would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Please include the code with the websocket that is not working so it's easier for someone to help you with your question. You could add the data from the websocket response to your component state and use this in the component render method. When you update the state the component will re-render automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to append cities to the current list when you receive them from the socket, then maybe you don't need a separate `newCities` array in your state. Just `push` or `concat` the new cities onto the existing `cities` array.

For example, if your socket emits a `newCity` event with a single city as data, you could do something like this:

```
mySocket.addEventListener('newCity', (event) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ cities: prevState.cities.push(event.data) }));
});
```